# Making a Tip Calculator in javascript where users can enter their desired tip% and calculate button isn't working

Tags: javascript, html

Here is my HTML code.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html lang="en">

<head>

<meta charset="UTF-8">

<title>Tip Calculator</title>

<link rel="stylesheet" href="midtermcss.css">

<script src="http://html5shiv.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/html5.js"</script>

<script src="midtermJS.js"></script>

</head>

<body>
<section>
    <h1 id="heading">Tip Calculator</h1>

    <label for="billAmount">Total Amount Of Bill:</label>
    <input type="text" id="billAmount"><br>

    <label for="percentTip">Percent To Tip:</label>
    <input type="text" id="percentTip"><br>

    <label for="amountPeople">How Many People?:</label>
    <input type="text" id="amountPeople"><br>

    <label for="totalTip">Tip Total:</label>
    <input type="text" id="totalTip" disabled="disabled"><br>

    <label>&nbsp;</label>
    <input  type="button" id="calculate" value="Calculate"><br>
  </section>
 </body>
</html>
```

The HTML I think is fine but it shows the names of everything that I think you would need to help me understand this button situation.

This is the JavaScript portion and I know the error is in here but I just can't seem to figure it out. After scouring the internet for 2 days and watching "how to create a button" tutorials over and over it is still not making sense to me. I click "Calculate" and nothing happens, so I know its with the button.

```
var $ = function (id) {
return document.getElementById(id);
}
var calculateClick = function () {
    var billAmount = parseFloat( $("billAmount").value );
    var percentTip = parseFloat( $("rate").value );
    var amountPeople = parseInt( $("years").value );

if (isNaN(billAmount) || billAmount <= 0) {
    alert("Your bill can't be 0 or less.");
} 

else if(isNaN(percentTip) || percentTip <= 0) {
    alert("The percentage should be a whole number.");
}

else if(isNaN(amountPeople) || amountPeople <= 0) {
    alert("You are 1 person never count yourself as less.");
}

else {
    var total = billAmount * (percentTip / 100) / amountPeople;

    $("totalTip").value = total.toFixed(2);
} 
}

window.onload = function () {
$("Calculate").onclick = calculateClick;
$("billAmount").focus();
}
```

Comment: trying changing the button type to 'submit'

Comment: IDs are case sensitive. `calculate`  vs `Calculate`

Comment: What errors do you see in the console? I see what looks like jQuery in your code, but you don't appear to have included jQuery.

Comment: You are missing a closing bracket in your HTML file when you include html5.js from googlecode.com

Comment: You are also looking for elements called rate and years that do not exist in the calculateClick function

Comment: The submit button would make this close and refresh though wouldn't it? Techedryan?

Comment: Ahh. lol thats it so what I get for stealing code from another assignment nice catch Jeff Carey, I had "rate" and "years" instead of "amountPeople" and "percentTip"...........4 days I've been re-doing this button over and over again..............THANK YOU!!!! I'm such a dunce Ha!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check out this pen for a working version: http://codepen.io/anon/pen/avaRVm

First, case sensitivity, as mentioned in the comments: `calculate` does not equal `Calculate`.

The bigger problem is here:

```
var percentTip = parseFloat( $("rate").value );
var amountPeople = parseInt( $("years").value );
```

and here:

```
<label for="percentTip">Percent To Tip:</label>
<input type="text" id="percentTip"><br>

<label for="amountPeople">How Many People?:</label>
<input type="text" id="amountPeople"><br>
```

In your HTML, you don't use `rate` and `years` as IDs; you use `percentTip` and `amountPeople`. If you get those to match up, then your code will work.

Comment: Yeah Chinaowl you nailed it jeff carey nailed it just before you. and as soon as he said "rate" i looked at my code and saw it, I have no clue how i didn't see that for 4 days......I feel like an idiot because I emailed my teacher about it too.    Thank you guys so much!